# How can I use babel-plugin-import with babel 5.x?

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader

I'm trying to use `babel-plugin-import` to import `antd` in an old project that uses `babel-core@5.4.7` and `babel-loader@5.1.2`.

How can I get `babel-plugin-import` to work with current configuration? Or is there any older version of `babel-plugin-import` plugin that would go with it?

Answer (score 1):

Babel 5's plugin system was very different from Babel 6's, so it is unlikely that any current plugins will work on Babel 5.